# Verify phone number with Android phone efficiently

Tags: android, sms-gateway

The problem that I have is the SMS gateway not working very well when I need to verify the phone number. I'm using [Clickatell](https://www.clickatell.com/)
Sometimes working, sometimes no. Users are very angry with us because the request the sms and they never receive it.
I need a service or **another way** to verify the phone number efficiently.
The problem is the users country (south and center America like argentina, uruguay, paraguay, ecuador, panama, etc). The most of t he SMS gateway not working righ in this kind of country.
Another alternative? May be a phone call or something.
Thanks!

Comment: You can use Twilio, they have the same sort of issues with SMS, but they offer a phone call option as well. Typically you would put this functionality on your server, and have your app tell your server to send the SMS or make a phone call.

Comment: @danielnugent phone call is better than sms?

Comment: Always give the user SMS as a first choice.  If that doesn't work, give them the option of a phone call.

Comment: But the phone call is 100% delivery rate?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter's digits (https://get.digits.com/) is one of the best ways to check user validation through the phone number (SMS OTP) and it's totally **FREE**. :)

Digits are powered by Twitter’s infrastructure. Take seconds to integrate with your project. Just download the fabric plugin for android studio from digit website.

[image]

It supports unlimited Authentications, supports multi-Languages,   supports International Numbers, supports Custom themes etc.

Comment: Now i have an hybrid app building with phobegap. Ca I integrate it?

Comment: not sure.. you can check the steps and let me know if it's possible - https://fabric.io/kits/android/digits/install